# Recursive column in sql (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion

I have a equation:

`result[n] = least(0, x[n] + result[n-1])`

which should produce such a table

```
  x  | result
--------------
 100 |     0  // least(100+0, 0) = 0
  50 |     0  // least(50+0, 0) = 0
-100 |  -100  // least(-100+0, 0) = -100
  50 |   -50  // least(50-100, 0) = -50
```

I'd like to somehow use it in SQL query for table of x values. I've been thinking about `lag` function like this:

```
select
    *,
    greatest(0, lag(result) over (order by i) + "table1"."value") as result
from
    table1
```

but of course it won't work since table has no result column.

Do you have any idea how to achieve such a recursion in SQL (PostgreSQL)?

Comment: See [Can window function LAG reference the column which value is being calculated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34338991/1995738)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You can do this, but I need to assume that you have a column specifying the ordering.

If so, you can use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive t as (
      select v.*
      from (values (1, 100), (2, 50), (3, -100), (4, 50)) v(id, x)
    ),
    cte(id, x, result) as (
     select id, x, least(x, 0)
     from t
     where id = 1
     union all
     select t.id, t.x, least(t.x + cte.result, 0)
     from cte join
          t
          on t.id = cte.id + 1
    )
select cte.*
from cte
order by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2992184c7ba48017a8d20fb5381e8152) is a db<>fiddle.